# Extjs4, aligning a field right in an anchor layout

Tags: layout, extjs, extjs4, alignment, anchor

I want to place my fields, in an anchor layout, in the right. When I add a field with `anchor: '50%'` in this layout, it will be displayed like this:
[image]

How can I place it in the right.

Answer (score 1):

This anchor layout is not meant for this kind of layout.  Use a column or table layout instead.

The only way you could come close to achieving what you want with the anchor layout is to use a pixel based offset, which doesn't make sense since you are using percentages for the width of the fields.